# When to use or not use DATE_ADD in mysql

Tags: mysql, dateadd

Trying to figure out if there is any difference between two queries when I want to find records older than two years.

The queries are:

```
   SELECT kundNr FROM kundorder 
   WHERE datum <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR;

   SELECT kundNr FROM kundorder 
   WHERE datum <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 2 YEAR);
```

The table is like this:

```
orderNr| kundNr| anstNr| datum
'1',   |  '4', | '4',  |'2017-03-05'
'2',   |   '2',| '4',  | '2017-05-01'
'3',   |   '4',| '4',  | '2017-10-01'
'4',   |   '1',| '1',  | '2017-10-01'
'5',   |   '3',| '4',  | '2017-10-01'
'6',   |   '3',| '4',  | '2017-10-02'
'7',   |   '3',| '1',  | '2017-10-03'
'8',   |   '4',| '1',  | '2017-10-04'
'9',   |   '6',| '4',  | '2017-10-05'
'10',  |   '6',| '1',  | '2017-10-01'
'11',  |   '1',| '4',  | '2016-10-01'
'12',  |   '2',| '1',  | '2015-01-01'
'13',  |   '2',| '1',  | '2017-10-06'
'14',  |   '5',| '1',  | '2016-05-01'
```

I can see in my small sample database both produce a correct result but what is the difference between them? Is there any case where one would work and the other one won't?

Comment: They should be the same.

Comment: @GordonLinoff so I shouldn't be to bothered which to use? I think it it might be me not understanding how/when to use `date_add` but I might do that when I actually have to use it someday.